# Android development - calendar's events get/put

Tags: android, android-calendar

I want to progmatically get/put events from the calendar of the device before SDK 14.

I found this:
http://code.google.com/p/android-calendar-provider-tests/source/browse/trunk/src/com/androidbook/androidcalendar/CalendarActivity.java

But this only works from Activity's onCreate method. I tried call methods from outside onCreate, but it's not working.

I have a class extends ArrayAdapter and i want to call from this (onClick an element) another own class methot, that put event to calendar.

I tried search solution over many hours, but pointless...